# Where can i find any information about ancient doshell(8)?

Tags: linux, console, tty, history

I check the openvt manual by running "man openvt" command, and i found doshell(8) under "SEE ALSO" section:

[image]

But there's no manual if i do "man 8 doshell":

[image]

I checked the online manual at http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_openvt.htm, the **doshell(8)** is not a link:

[image]

I found someone mentioned "(There is also the ancient doshell(8)", answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21428158/how-to-send-broadcast-message-to-console-in-linux-from-c-program

[image]

Just a question out of my curiosity, is there any place i can find information about doshell(8)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure (it has been a while) but it looks to me that is a reference to the old Linux routine (1992): ftp://ftp2.de.freebsd.org/pub/linux/tsx-11/sources/usr.bin/doshell.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <errno.h>

extern char *sys_errlist[];

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    if (argc != 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: doshell <ttyname> <shellname> &\n");
    exit(1);
    }

    /* close down fd's */
    close(0);
    close(1);
    close(2);

    /* detach from parent process's group */
    setsid();

    /* open new tty */
    if (open(argv[1], O_RDWR, 0) == -1)
    exit(2);
    dup(0);
    dup(0);
    execlp(argv[2], "-", 0);
    /* should appear on new tty...: */
    fprintf(stderr, "can't exec shell: %s\n", sys_errlist[errno]);
    exit(3);
}
```

It might also refer to the older Minux routine: http://users.sosdg.org/~qiyong/mxr/source/commands/mail/mail.c#L702

```
void doshell(command)
char *command;
{
  int waitstat, pid;
  char *shell;

  if (NULL == (shell = getenv("SHELL"))) shell = SHELL;

  if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
        perror("mail: couldn't fork");
        return;
  } else if (pid != 0) {        /* parent */
        wait(&waitstat);
        return;
  }

  /* Child */
  setgid(getgid());
  setuid(getuid());
  umask(oldmask);

  execl(shell, shell, "-c", command, (char *) NULL);
  fprintf(stderr, "can't exec shell\n");
  exit(127);
}
```

Both routines seem to have the functionality as described in the stackoverflow answer, and it doesn't seem unlikely the first derived from the second.